# Preparing a large 3D file (OBJ) in Unity for Oculus Quest

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, oculusquest

I have a large (700MB) .obj 3D file from a Faro Laser 3D scanner.
Meshlab tells me that it is 6 297 704 vertices and 12 395 899 faces. a bit too much for the Oculus Quest as it looks like. but if I reduce it to e.g. only 100 000 vertices all details will be lost. I still have the point cloud too.

Can I prepare the file in a way that it can be processed by Unity and the Oculus Quest?

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well you can search for a better reduction algorithm .. but reducing any mesh to about `1.5%` of it's original vertice data It is quite obvious that some details will get lost ....

Comment: If you post a picture of your current before-after results, it might help to understand what could be optimized (if anything).